# How do I get both the Onclick function to work and the href

Tags: html, model-view-controller

Below is my code, it serves two functions 1 to fire the action in the controller, which it does, and 2 to active the tab panel which is does not. What am I doing wrong.

```
<l1 class="active">
                        <a href="#tab1" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("communitiesLanding","home", new {id = 0})'" data-toggle="tab">Registered</a></li>
                        <l1><a href="#tab2" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("communitiesLanding","home", new {id = 1})'" data-toggle="tab">Certified</a></li>
```

Here is my old code with my ajax call:

```
 <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" onclick="setCert(0);" data-toggle="tab">Registered</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="#tab2" onclick="setCert(1);" data-toggle="tab">Certified</a></li>
```

javascript:

```
   function setCert(cert){
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Home/CommunitiesLanding/' + cert,
                type: "GET",
                traditional: true,
                contentType: "application/json",

                success: function () {

                    console.log('success!!');
                }
            });
```

Comment: Are you using jquery in your page?

Comment: I am using jquery and these tabs were working until I tried to focus on refreshing the page with these actions in the controller

Comment: You should probably do this via AJAX so you don't have to refresh the page.

Comment: I was trying to do that but that wasn't working either.

Comment: Why are you attaching a content type header to a GET request? There's no request body to describe the type of.